# Is it possible to interop with Thunderbird using C#?

Tags: c#, com, interop, thunderbird

Here's the latest hurdle in my ongoing quest to [automate my job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2836440/how-would-you-start-automating-my-job-part-2):

- All email in the company goes through 4 different email adresses, switching randomly back and forth (with a note attached in the global share: please set "keep email on server")
- All logic related to email is contained in a nice big Thunderbird profile, which gets copied back and forth to new machines; this includes sorting invoices into 5 different "folders", the list of VIP adresses to send notifications, and the VIP level of those customers
- I only need the contents of those folders (the attachments, anyway)

The question: is there a way to ask Thunderbird for those attachments and lists from C#? Alternatively, can Outlook be set up to synchronize with Thunderbird? Where do I start reading?

Ditching Thunderbird is not an option right now, I need to keep up with changes to the VIP list.

P.S. I will set up a real email server right after Monkey saves me enough time to convince people about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though I have never used it, I guess it should be possible through XPCOM.

More information about XPCOM here:

http://xpcomviewer.mozdev.org/

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Development_resources

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Calling_Thunderbird_from_other_programs

Hope this helps

Adriano

Comment: No C# there. Guess Monkey will have to learn Python to talk to the Bird.

Comment: You should be able to write a C++ wrapper over the Thunderbird XPCOM (I guess XPCOM models functionality in classes/interfaces in the same way COM does) classes you are interested and access these classes from C#

Comment: Hmm.. sounds nice, thank you. I wish I could upvote you twice.